# How can I add a scale on react leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using react with the library leaflet but I would like to add on my map a scale in kilometers.

How can I do to do that ?

Here is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import './styles.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    center: [51.505, -0.091],
    zoom: 13,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <Marker position={this.state.center}>
            <Popup>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And this is the link :

[Map](https://codesandbox.io/s/2wnv7o1mlr?file=/src/index.js:0-858)

I saw that :

[Documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#control-scale)

But I didn't find any examples on how to implement that in my code...

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the [React Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org) library, another alternative would be to import ScaleControl like so

```
import { ScaleControl } from 'react-leaflet'
```

and then you can just add the scale by adding `<ScaleControl />` inside `<MapContainer></MapContainer>` and add different attributes such as position. For example,

```
  <MapContainer>
    <ScaleControl position="topleft" />
  </MapContainer>
```

Finally, you can always use CSS to edit the appearance of the scale.

Answer (score 3):

create a simple react-leaflet object

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import L from "leaflet";
import { useLeafletMap } from "use-leaflet";

const MapScale = ({ options }) => {
  const map = useLeafletMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    L.control.scale(options).addTo(map);
  }, [map]);

  return null;
};

export default MapScale;
```

then in your main page, simply add `<MapScale options={{imperial:false}}/>`

Answer (score 2):

Nothing simpler, just use it:

```
import { ScaleControl } from 'react-leaflet';


<ScaleControl imperial={false} />
```

By default, the location is in the lower left corner of the map.